# C# same namespace in different files

Tags: c#, namespaces

I tried to move implementation to other file and got Error in Form1.cs "OpenPort doesn't exist in the curent context"
Any suggestions, please?

```
Form1.cs

namespace MyApp 
{ 
    void Form1Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        OpenPort(); 
    }
}

Port.cs

namespace MyApp 
{ 
    public static void OpenPort();
}
```

Comment: This is terrible `public static void OpenPort();` directly in namespace?

Comment: I think methods should take place inside classes, not directly inside namespaces. If you marked the class `partial`, certainly the method should be able to call on same namespace.

Comment: Put your `OpenPort` function into a static class called `Port` and then call it with `Port.OpenPort();`

Comment: Jenish Rabadiya
OK, I see static is unnecessary there, byt answer stll remains
So C# hate global variables and functions?

Comment: No, it's just that it can't find the method because you haven't put it in a class. Haven't you got the error "A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods" too?

Comment: did you just not post the classes for simplicity? I guess with this code you will get other error messages then just "OpenPort doesn't exist in the curent context"? could you please post a code that is simplified but still compileable, so that the error becomes obvious. Up to now it is much more then just the issue of a *global variable*

Comment: Davide Vitali. No, I didn't, maybe because I use SharpDevelop IDE

Comment: Thanks to everybody answered
I solved problem by adding class

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't declare methods or properties directly in a namespace. You have to declare a class first, in which you write your methods. Then, if you want to "spread" the same class in different files, you ought to add the `partial` keyword.

```
Form1.cs

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        public void Form1Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenPort();
        }
    }
}

Port.cs

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        public static void OpenPort()
        {
            // your implementation here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of a namespace like a container. Just like any other container you can put stuff in it. An advantage of namespaces is that they can group functionality together without you needing to put everything in the same file - of particular use when programs get large. Namespaces are also a way of keeping names separate. Think of roads - both London Road and High Street may both have a number 18 but 18 London Road and 18 High Street are different and distinguishable.

For example, `MyNamespace` contains `MyClass` and `MyClass` contains `MyMethod`

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass 
    {
        void MyMethod() {}
    }
}
```

To use `MyMethod` from another namespace you need to add a `using` statement for `MyNamespace`.

Taking this a step further imagine `MyOtherNamespace` contains `MyClass` and `MyClass` contains `MyMethod`
`MyOtherNamespace` also contains `MyClass` and `MyClass` also contains `MyMethod`

```
namespace MyOtherNamespace
{
    class MyClass 
    {
        void MyMethod() {}
    }
}
```

As before, to use `MyMethod` from another namespace you need to add a `using` statement for `MyOtherNamespace`.

If you want to use `MyMethod` from both `MyNamespace` and `MyOtherNamespace` you must tell your program which one to use by adding the Namespace name to the call like this

```
MyNamespace.MyClass.MyMethod();
MyOtherNamespace.MyClass.MyMethod();
```

The same rule applies if you've got multiple classes with the same method in the same namespace - the difference being you don't need to include the namespace

```
MyFirstClass.MyMethod();
MySecondClass.MyMethod();
```

On a related note, you can also split a class between multiple files using the `partial` keyword. For example, you could turn this

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass 
    {
        void MyMethod() {}
        void MyOtherMethod() {}
    }
}
```

Into this

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    partial class MyClass 
    {
        void MyMethod() {}
    }

    partial class MyClass 
    {
        void MyOtherMethod() {}
    }
}
```

Functionally they're the same and in both cases you'd call the methods like this

```
MyClass.MyMethod();
MyClass.MyOtherMethod();
```